# Active files in Accurev's snapshot

Tags: accurev

We use Accurev 6.1. I've got the following configuration in Accurev:

- the snapshot stream backed with the main stream
- the dynamic stream backed with the snapshot
- my workspace backed with the dynamic stream

[image: my configuration]

From the other hand some our developers have their workspaces backed with the snapshot directly (it is not shown on the image)

From "Accurev Concept Manual" I know that the snapshot is the configuration that never changes. However I see that there are some active files in the snapshot.

How is it possible? What does it mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not have a snapshot stream.

You have a dynamic stream with a time basis applied (clock icon on the left hand side, snapshot streams have a camera icon).

You can promote to/from a time based stream and remove/change the time basis any any time.

Thats why you are seeing active files in this stream.

To prevent promotes into a stream, you need to apply a stream lock.

Comment: Ok. Let it be "stream1 <- stream 2 <- my workspace".
Is it correct that when someone promotes to the stream 1, it automatically updates the stream 2, and I can take these changes into my workspace with 'accurev update' command?

Comment: If the file which was promoted into stream1 is not active (member status) in stream2, then yes, it will be inherited into stream2 and you will update your workspace to pull in that change.  Otherwise, the file in stream2 is overlapped and will require a merge to clear the conflict.  Once the overlap is cleared, you will update your workspace to pull in that change.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I want to know